# Cascade insert in hibernate and unique constraint on cascading table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a following SQL schema layout:

```
-- postgresql82+ syntax

create table AudioTracks (
  id serial primary key 
, name text
, size integer
, filePath text
, additionDate timestamp default now()
);

create table Genres (
  id serial primary key
, name text unique -- here is the unique constraint which troubles me 
, description text
, additionDate timestamp default now()
);

create table AudioTrackGenre (
  genreId integer references Genres (id) unique 
, audioTrackId integer references AudioTracks (id) unique 
, additionDate timestamp default now()
);
```

And two corresponding mappings to tables:

```
@Entity(name = "AudioTracks")
public class AudioTrack implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private Integer size;

    @Column
    private String filePath;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date additionDate;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinTable(name = "AudioTrackGenre",
            joinColumns =  { @JoinColumn(name = "audioTrackId") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "genreId") }
    )
    @OrderBy("name")
    private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<Genre>();

    // setter/getter methods //
    ....
}
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "Genres")
public class Genre implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date additionDate;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres")
    private Set<AudioTrack> audioTracks = new HashSet<AudioTrack>();

    public Genre() { }
    public Genre(String name) { this.name = name; }

    // setter/getter methods //
    ....
}
```

But whenever i am trying to save AudioTrack, populated with Genres which are already exists in Genres table, like here:

```
        Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<Genre>();
        genres.add(new Genre("ambient"));

        AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack();
        track.setGenres(genres);

        audioTrackService.addAudioTrack(track);
```

(the `audioTrackService.addAudioTrack(track)` thing does `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(track)` at lowest DAO level)

i am getting:

```
ERROR: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "genres_name_key"
  Detail: Key (name)=(ambient) already exists.
```

How do i tell Hibernate not to try to re-insert already existing genres to `Genres` table on cascade inserts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the genre already exists, you must provide its id.

Look at this line: `new Genre("ambient")`.

How could hibernate possibly guess what is the existing id of the Genre ambient?

Hibernate tries to insert the corresponding genre, because you haven't provided its id.

When you insert the audio track, hibernate must inserts records in the AudioTrackGenre table. Hibernate must know the ids of the genres. Otherwise hibernate assumes they are new genres.

**Edit:**

It seems you are adding genres on demand(like StackOverflow tags).

You can do the following in your code:

```
for (String genreName : submittedTextGenres) {
   Genre genre = genreDAO.findByName(genre);
   if (genre == null) { //a new genre
      genre = new Genre(genreName);
   }

   audioTrack.addGenre(genre);
}
```

If you are afraid of a concurrent user adding the same genres: (suggestion by `JB Nizet`)

```
for (String genreName : submittedTextGenres) {
   Genre genre = genreDAO.findByName(genre);
   if (genre == null) { //a new genre
      try {
         genre = genreDAO.insertGenre(genre); //a transaction
      } catch (GenreExistsException) {
         genre = genreDAO.findByName(genre); //a separate transaction
      }
   }

   audioTrack.addGenre(genre);
}
```

Comment: But how do i provide an id for each of track.genres, which are asigned by database in end of the ends and thus unknown before genre was inserted?

Comment: I can't understand your use case. If you are adding genres to an audio track, then the genres exist in the database. Just load the genres from the database and add the appropriate genres to the audiotrack.

Comment: So i have no option but to do manual fetching, checking that there is no such genre already and then - insertion of each newly specified genre and can't rely on cascading insert at all? But what if this genre was added by some other user at very unfortunate time after checking, but before inserting? Is there any alternative to pessimistic locking?

Comment: In my case, genres are much like tags, added in free form in text-field, like `"ambient generic dark psyche"` and supposed to be created on-demand.

Comment: I have edited my post. If you are afraid of a concurrent user adding the same genres and you don't want to use pessimistic locking, then I think you have to give up cascading insert. I mean first you have to add the new genres to the database.

Comment: +1, although the second solution won't eliminate the possibility of two users creating the same genre at the same time. Transactions run in isolation. You would need to create the genre in a separate transaction, catch the exception caused by concurrent creation, and get the genre created by the other transaction to do that.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Thank you, you are right. When would you choose pessimistic locking over your proposed solution? I have edited my post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: I wouldn't. The probability of concurrent creations is very small, and there's an easy way to recover from the exception caused by the optimistic approach.